# Is there an equivalent to book-keeping package "Pastel" in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Here in South Africa people use Windows with a software package called `pastel`. It is a book keeping package for medium to **very** large corporates and have the monopoly here.  Are there any thing in that class for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general they are likely to be closed as off topic.

In your case , see http://wiki.clug.org.za/wiki/Comparison_between_Quasar_and_Pastel_Accounting_software

See also

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareEquivalents

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Linux_software_equivalent_to_Windows_software

http://www.linuxalt.com/

Comment: May I add: http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20080927164237918/Financial.html